# how to use vector and struct members in method

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, struct

im new in c++ (and not to old in programming...) and i have problem with handling vectors and strucs in class.
basically i have a vector and a array of pointers to struct members in the class and i want work on the in my methos but im doing something worng/

here is my movement.h

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;
class movement
{
private:
    static const int MAX_ROW_PER_TRACKER = 100;
    static const int MIN_TO_START_CALC = 30;
    static const int MAX_TRACKERS = 20;

    struct tracker
    {
        int id;
        double a[MAX_ROW_PER_TRACKER];
        double b[MAX_ROW_PER_TRACKER];
        double c;
    };
    vector<int> trackersOrder[MAX_TRACKERS] = {};
    tracker* trackersArr[MAX_TRACKERS];

public:
    movement();
    void addRow(int a, int b, int c);
    ~movement();
};
```

and my movement.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "movement.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

movement::movement()
{
}

void movement::addRow(int id, int a, int b)
{
    int index;
    vector<int>::iterator searchID = find(trackersOrder.begin(), trackersOrder.end(), ID);
    if (searchID == trackersOrder.end())
    {
        vector<int>::iterator freeLocation = find(trackersOrder.begin(), trackersOrder.end(), 0); 
        index = freeLocation - trackersOrder.begin();
        trackersOrder.insert(trackersOrder.begin + index, id);
        structArr[index] = new tracker;
        structArr[index]->id = id;
        structArr[index]->a[0] = a;
        structArr[index]->b[0] = b;
        structArr[index]->c = 0;
    }

}

movement::~movement()
{
}
```

so when i send to method "addRow" id, and b i want to first check if i allready have this id in my vector (the vector just give me the index for the structs array) and if not then if put the id in the first empty place in the vector and on the structs array/
but from some reasin its look to me that the methid dont reconized the vector and the structs. can you help me understand why?
p.s - i can bet that i have more mistakes in my code, its my firs try with pointers and ect. (im comming from the good life in Matlab) so i will be happy to learn on them also
thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like you have a typo.  Shouldn't `structArr` be `trackersArr`?

Answer (score 1):

**The main problem**

The problem is that in your code,  `trackersOrder` is not a vector but an array of vectors:

```
vector<int> trackersOrder[MAX_TRACKERS] = {};  // array of MAXTRACKERS vectors !!
```

**The solution**

If you define it as simple vector, it should work better:

```
vector<int> trackersOrder;
```

If you want to set its size do it in the  movement constructor:

```
movement::movement() : trackersOrder(MAX_TRACKERS)
{
}
```

**Other issues**

There is a case typo with an `ID` that should be `id`.

```
auto searchID = find(trackersOrder.begin(), trackersOrder.end(), id);  // by the way auto is easier + ID corrected
```

There are a missing `()` after a `begin` whicn transforms unfortunately your iterator arithmetic into function pointer arithmetic (sic!!):

```
    trackersOrder.insert(trackersOrder.begin() + index, id); // corrected
```

Finally, there are a couple of structArr that should be replaced by trackersArr.

The result does finally compile ([online demo](http://ideone.com/KPNB93))

Comment: wow thank you its help me a lot! can i ask something more? if i the rest of the program i want to delete only one member from the struct array (from the end/middle or end of the array) how can i do that?

Comment: For vectors, jus use [`erase()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/).  For arrays it's more difficult.  The easiest approach would be to get rid of them and only use vectors.  If you want to keep arrays, you could think of [`copy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) to overwrite the element to delete with the ones that follow.

Comment: ok thanks you again. i will think on that. i have to solve last problem for today but i think that my brain force me to leave. why when i called the "addRow" method from my main witthe instance 's', after initialization, like this: "s.addRow(id, a, b);" its throw me "expression must have a class type" error?

Comment: @Nadavp I'd suggest to ask a new question, with the current status f the code, including this new part. It'll be easier to see where the problem is ;-)